# Making all Div Sizes the same CSS Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, resize

So Records divs Must all be the same Size throughout.

I wanted to add records by column but all having the same size div. Is this possible? so the more I add, columns will be the same size & resize.

```
 |1| |2| |3|
 |6| | | | |

 |1| |2| |3|
 | | | | | |

 |1| |2| |3|
 | | | | | |

<wrapper>
  <div class="column1">
     <div class="record">1 <br> 6</div>
     <div class="record">1</div>
     <div class="record">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
     <div class="record">2</div>
     <div class="record">2</div>
     <div class="record">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
     <div class="record">3</div>
     <div class="record">3</div>
     <div class="record">3</div>
  </div>
 </wrapper>
```

Answer (score 1):

Having columns that are the same size is really as simple as setting **[`display: flex`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)** on your `wrapper` along with **[`flex-grow: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)** on `.column`. This tells the columns that they should grow to to fill the available space.

If you want there to be equidistant space between rows, that's automatically handled for you by flexbox; all you need to do is specify that the rows should take up `100%` of the height of their container with `height: 100%`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.record {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<wrapper>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="record">1 <br> 6</div>
    <div class="record">1</div>
    <div class="record">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="record">2</div>
    <div class="record">2</div>
    <div class="record">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="record">3</div>
    <div class="record">3</div>
    <div class="record">3</div>
  </div>
</wrapper>
```

And adding more columns simply reduces the gap between each column, keeping the columns equidistant from each other:

```css
wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.record {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<wrapper>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="record">1 <br> 6</div>
    <div class="record">1</div>
    <div class="record">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="record">2</div>
    <div class="record">2</div>
    <div class="record">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="record">3</div>
    <div class="record">3</div>
    <div class="record">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="record">4</div>
    <div class="record">4</div>
    <div class="record">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="record">5</div>
    <div class="record">5</div>
    <div class="record">5</div>
  </div>
</wrapper>
```

Comment: I want toe records to grow no the column

Comment: In that case you simply need to add `height: 100%` to `.record`. I've updated my answer to showcase this.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 32px;
}
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.column > div {
margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border:1px solid;
  width:20px;
  text-align:center
}
.column{
flex: 10%;
    max-width: 10%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container ">
<div class="column">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  </div>
<div class="column">
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  </div>
<div class="column">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```